# Subshell command in Docker

Tags: docker

In a build process I need to call `zipalign` which is on a certain path in the docker container that I'm using:

```
$ docker run nathansamson/flutter-builder-docker:v0.7.3 find . -iname zipalign
./opt/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/28.0.1/zipalign
```

This path can change, if the docker container is updated and there is a new android sdk. For example this could be the path in the future:

```
$ docker run nathansamson/flutter-builder-docker:v0.9.9 find . -iname zipalign
./opt/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/42.0.0/zipalign
```

So instead of hardcoding the call to

```
docker run nathansamson/flutter-builder-docker:v0.7.3 \
/opt/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/28.0.1/zipalign -h
```

I would like a generic solution that finds the path to zipalign automatically. I have tried it with a subshell

```
$ docker run nathansamson/flutter-builder-docker:v0.7.3 $(find . -iname zipalign) -h
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: 
container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"-h\": 
executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.
ERRO[0001] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

and with a wildcard for the folder:

```
$ docker run nathansamson/flutter-builder-docker:v0.7.3 /opt/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/*/zipalign -h 
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: 
container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: 
\"/opt/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/*/zipalign\": stat /opt/android- 
sdk-linux/build-tools/*/zipalign: no such file or directory": unknown.
ERRO[0001] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

So subshells and wildcard don't work in Docker. Any ideas how I can find the path to zipalign whenever I'm calling it?

Answer (score 2):

In your Dockerfile you control the entire environment.  It's often easiest to cause things to appear in their "natural" places, like `/usr/bin`.  You also have the advantage that, within a single Docker image, there will only be one version of the tools installed.

I might do something like this:

```sh
RUN for f in $PWD/opt/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/*/*; do \
      ln -s $f /usr/local/bin; \
    done
CMD ["zipalign", "-h"]
```

Another approach that might work is to use a build argument or an environment variable to hold the version number.  If you do that then you can set up a known path name.

```sh
ARG version
RUN curl -LO http://.../android-sdk-linux-${version}.tar.gz \
 && tar xzf android-sdk-linux-${version}.tar.gz \
 && rm -f android-sdk-linux-${version}.tar.gz \
 && cd opt/android-sdk-linux-build-tools \
 && ln -s ${version} current
CMD ["./opt/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/current/zipalign"]
```

Answer (score 1):

find can execute something by using the `-exec` option.

```
find . -name zipalign -exec bash -c '"$0"' {} \;
```

In your example:

```
docker run nathansamson/flutter-builder-docker:v0.7.3 find . -name zipalign -exec bash -c '"$0"' {} \;
```

Answer (score -1):

If there is nothing that can give you any hints, and you need to just find it, then `find` will probably do it. Something like:

```
find /opt -name zipalign -type f
```

If you can give it more specific starting point, instead of just /opt, then it will run faster.

If you want to execute it (and pass in "-h") in one line, you could do:

```
$(find /opt -name zipalign -type f) -h
```

Comment: I'm aware of how find works, but I can't get it to work in Docker. Have you tried `docker run nathansamson/flutter-builder-docker:v0.7.3 $(find /opt -name zipalign -type f) -h` ?